# Insert parameter in template literal for fetch URI in React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, template-literals

Utilizing .then with fetch uri insertion of '...${currency}.json' parameter runs correctly w/ no error:

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetch(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/${currency}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => setData(res[currency]))
}, [currency])
```

Utilizing async await with fetch uri insertion of '...${currency}.json' parameter gives a syntax error at parameter insertion'...${currency}.json':

```
const useCurrencyInfo2 = (currency) => {
   const [data, setData] = useState({});
   const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchCurrency = async () => {
         try {
            const resp = await fetch(`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fawazahmed0/currency-api@1/latest/currencies/${currency}.json`)

            if (!resp.ok) {
               setIsError(true)
               return
            }
            const json = await resp.json()
            setData(json[currency])

         } catch (error) {
            setIsError(true)
         }
      }
      fetchCurrency();
   }, [currency])
  
   return data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second snippet, inside the effect you define variable `currency`, which shadows original `currency` from hook parameters.

```
const currency = await resp.json()
```

Now, browser, when executing fetch knows that there will be variable `currency` in current scope, but it's not defined yet. So it throws an error when you try not-yet defined variable. To fix this you'll need to use different variable name for response's json:

```
const json = await resp.json()
setData(json[currency])
```

Comment: That is value, but the issue that I mentioned occurs in the fetch(`...${currency}.json')

Comment: Did you tried what I suggested in the answer?

Comment: Yes I tried that, and it was definitely a problem,,, but it doesn't resolve the syntax issue here fetch(`...${currency}.json')

Comment: Could you show resulting code and exact error you get then?

Comment: Running this doesn't produce an actual error, just no data.      if you paste the 2nd snippet in your VS Code you will see red for the entire literal declaration-- fetch(`..... ${currency}.json`)